# VS Code sample remote containers hang on starting server

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tried to use both the Node and Python sample dev containers from Microsoft but they always hang on starting the server. I've tried both "Open Repository in container.." and "Open Folder in container.." but it never gets passed the `Forwarding local port` step. It doesn't crash or throw an error or timeout, just sits there until I cancel it. Has anyone else experienced this? I wondered if it was my firewall but I can't see anything in the logs that it's being blocked.
Let me know if you need some more info/details.

The container in the image has been stuck at this step for about 8 hours...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhuLO.png

Answer (score 0):

This is/was a bug in the Insiders build of VS Code.